# How can I read Thread Group threads and loop count from a file?

Tags: jmeter

I have a large csv data set for users and depending on where I'm at in testing, like debugging the test, running a smaller dataset as a sanity check, or a full large dataset, I'd like to have some test defaults in a file. I'd also like to have this file shared between a group of sepaarate  jmeter tests.

I created another csv file, read it first with another CSV Data Set, and the variables work for Http Defaults as an example, perfect. However I am unable to use these variables for threads and loop count for the Thread Group or for the name of the file to use for users in my main thread group.

Surely there is a way to read variable values from a file to initialize a thread group?

Comment: Shoot, after I came back to this when I was does with the other one I didn't catch yours wasn't the one already upvoted and listed that as the answer. I upvoted yours as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **JMeter Properties**.

From the [Apache JMeter Documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html),

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads and need to be referenced using the **__P** or **__property** function.

So you can define the properties you need directly in `jmeter.properties` or `user.properties` files - they live in JMeter's "bin" folder like:

```
Threads_count=1
```

This will be loaded by JMeter on startup and shared among threads. You can achieve this by editing the `jmeter.properties` or `user.properties` files. But it is recommended to edit the `user.properties` file.

But you have to do this like:

**In jmeter.properties** file:

[image]

**In user.properties** file:

[image]

Now, you can use the properties like this in your `Thread Group`:

```
${__P(Threads_count)}
```

To define the property value, see [__P](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function.

Similarly, you can use it for loop counts which will be shared among a group of separate JMeter tests.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is properties not variables.

Properties are shared among threads, Variables are not:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

So all you have to do is put your "properties" in jmeter_home/bin/user.properties, they will be loaded by JMeter on startup and shared among threads.

You can then use your properties using [__P](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function, example:

> ${__P(group1.threads)}

Will use property called group1.threads defined in user.properties